# How can I use IPython interactive shell in gdb? || How can I get tab-completion to work in gdb's Python-interactive (pi) shell?

Tags: python, gdb

Normally, in Python shells I can press Tab twice to get a list of prompts.

On the other hand, in gdb's Python shell (`pi` or `python-interactive` command), there's only gdb-style completion.

Example session:

```
$ gdb -q
(gdb) pi
>>> gdb
<module 'gdb' from '/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py'>
>>> gdb.TabTab
... nothing ...
>>> show TabTab
Display all 148 possibilities? (y or n)
ada                              exec-direction                   record
agent                            exec-done-display                remote
annotate                         exec-file-mismatch               remoteaddresssize
[...]
```

Python auto complete should be *at least* like this.

```
$ python
Python 3.X.Y ...
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.TabTab
sys.abiflags                              sys.hash_info
sys.addaudithook(                         sys.hexversion
sys.api_version                           sys.implementation
[...]
```

How can I get the same/similar thing in gdb? *in particular IPython shell with tab completion is fine.*

---

Failed attempts:

- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246725/how-do-i-add-tab-completion-to-the-python-shell)

  ```
  import readline
  import rlcompleter
  readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
  ```

  makes the shell output a literal tab when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed after `sys.` or similar.

  At least it does work for identifier tab completion (`aTabTab`) does list some entries)

  Looks like this is because of some interaction with gdb -- `get_completer_delims` get reset to some value every time, and if the code above is run then the tab completion *outside* gdb switches to "Python mode" as well.
- Use `background_zmq_ipython` causes segmentation fault, because some gdb API (such as `gdb.Value`) cannot be read from outside the main thread.
- Use `IPython.embed()` also make <kbd>Tab</kbd> output a literal tab character.
- The official gdb documentation https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Completion.html doesn't mention anything about Python.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways I've figured out.

I can't figure out any way to use the built-in `readline` library.
See the failed attempts in the question for more details.

---

1. Reset stdout and stderr before calling `IPython.embed`.

   ```py
   import sys
   sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
   sys.stderr=sys.__stderr__

   import IPython
   IPython.embed(colors="neutral")
   ```

   Remember to reset stdout and stderr afterwards to avoid possible issues.

   Reference:

   - [How to recognize whether a script is running on a tty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858623/how-to-recognize-whether-a-script-is-running-on-a-tty)
   - [IPython.embed() does not use terminal colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933400/ipython-embed-does-not-use-terminal-colors)

   IPython will only use tab-completion and color when *all* of stdin, stdout and stderr are tty devices.
   By default gdb sys.stdout and sys.stderr are gdb wrappers (so that gdb can do "press enter to continue"
   when pagination limit is exceeded)
2. Start a kernel, and start a console separately.

   ```py
   import IPython
   IPython.embed_kernel()
   ```

   Read the console output on how to connect, and how to exit the terminal from the remote console.

   Using [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68769973/5267751) it's also possible to exit the terminal remotely programmatically.
3. Start a kernel (the complex way)

   Read the source code of IPython to figure out how to start a kernel manually, and get the connection file path in the process.

   ```py
   import threading
   import subprocess
   import IPython
   from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
   import sys

   app = IPKernelApp.instance()
   app.initialize([])
   app.kernel.user_module = sys.modules[__name__]
   app.kernel.user_ns = locals()
   app.shell.set_completer_frame()

   def console_thread_run():
       subprocess.run(["jupyter-console", "--no-confirm-exit", "--existing", 
           app.abs_connection_file
           ])
       app.kernel.do_shutdown(restart=False)
   console_thread=threading.Thread(target=console_thread_run)
   console_thread.start()

   app.start()
   ```
4. Start a kernel using `background_zmq_ipython` (accesses internal property, might break at any time).

   The main difference is that `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` etc. are not affected. See `background_zmq_ipython`
   documentation and [ipython - Provide remote shell for Python script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148319/provide-remote-shell-for-python-script) for more details.

   ```py
   import subprocess
   import logging
   import threading

   from background_zmq_ipython import IPythonBackgroundKernelWrapper

   kernel_wrapper = IPythonBackgroundKernelWrapper(
           banner="", # default value is "Hello from background-zmq-ipython."
           user_ns=globals(),
           logger=logging.Logger("IPython", level=logging.INFO)
           # no handler
           # otherwise it will print "To connect another client to this IPython kernel" ...
           )
   kernel_wrapper.thread=threading.main_thread()  # workaround for assertions

   subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c",
       (
       "from jupyter_console.app import ZMQTerminalIPythonApp;"
       "app = ZMQTerminalIPythonApp();"
       "app.initialize();"
       "app.shell.own_kernel=True;"
       "app.start();"
       ),
       "--no-confirm-exit",
       "--existing", kernel_wrapper.connection_filename
       ])

   kernel_wrapper._thread_loop()
   ```

   Also show how to change the message "keeping kernel alive" to "Shutting down kernel".

Comment: Also answers: "*How can I use IPython in gdb?*" ■ Also for convenience it's also possible to call gdb commands from IPython: `from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic; register_line_magic("!")(lambda line: gdb.execute(line))` — Reference: [Defining custom magics — IPython 7.30.1 documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html)

Comment: Also to do that automatically, add `app.shell.client.execute('from ...', silent=True, store_history=False);` at an appropriate location.

Comment: And use [repr - Tell IPython to use an object's `__str__` instead of `__repr__` for output - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453624/tell-ipython-to-use-an-objects-str-instead-of-repr-for-output) to customize pretty printer of `gdb.Value` and `gdb.Type`.

Answer (score 0):

All of methods didn't work out of the box for me.

This is how I did in on debian 13:

```bash
$ gdb
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1 ...
(gdb) set $foo = 123
(gdb) print $foo
$1 = 123
(gdb) pi
>>> import IPython
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stderr=sys.__stderr__
>>> sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
>>> IPython.embed_kernel()
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may...

To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-713400.json
```

In another shell:

```bash
$ jupyter console --existing kernel-713400.json
Jupyter console 6.4.4
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0]
IPython 8.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

# gdb.exec<TAB> - works
In [1]: gdb.execute("print $foo")
$2 = 123
```